# How realistically practical is hydrokinetic flight?

Tags: internal-consistency, science-fiction, water, telekinesis

According to what I've looked up, the average human is 60% water, and 60% of that water is in cells. Lets assume this "hydrokinesis" is limited to telekinetically lifting and moving liquid water. Is there enough water distributed within the human body to allow the body to fly safely, comfortably, and practically in the air? Is there a very specific way the hydrokinesis has to be used on the body to achieve this?

*In case more specifics are needed:* Lets say a hydrokinetic person used this to float over a road and move like a car would on an average day through a city. Could this be used to reach normal car accelerations without accidentally ripping water out of the body? If this just complicates the question or doesn't make sense, feel free to ignore it.

Comment: If you want us to tell if something is possible, you have to explain us how it works. And you haven't, so far.

Comment: What, specifically, are you asking? (And why is this a [tag:reality-check] question? Did you take the time to read that tag's wiki?) If hydrokinesis is the ability to move water around, and if a gram of water existed in the center of a 100kg ball, then whether or not that ball could fly would depend on the energy the hydrokinetic person could apply to the water combined with the tendency of the water to break down (e.g., turn to steam, then plasma) when too much pressure is applied and the ability of the surrounding mass to take the pressure.

Comment: As for whether or not that is "realistically practical" depends on the rules of your world. Superman can fly in the world of DC Comics, so obviously hydrokinesis would be just fine in your world if you declare it to be so. This is why I'm asking for you to be more clear about what you're asking. What does "practical" and "realistic" mean in your world? (In the Real World it's neither practical nor realistic because it doesn't exist....) It might help if you review [this summary of the site's rules](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/q/8491/40609).

Comment: We need some specifics to work from here, for  a start how much water can a hydrokinetic manipulate, at what range, across what volume of space, how pure does it need to be, how fast can the water be moved, etc....

Comment: If you could fully explain how it works using science, it would be possible in real life but its not because its magic fantasy. instead, think about what the limits are of hydrokinesis and think of ways it might not work. for example, does using hydrokinesis heat up the liquid? id say if you dont control it correctly your body could rip apart, so the power needs to be evenly distributed across all your body. so basically, unless it heats up the body, id say sure yeah it is possible in my own view of it.

Comment: Also please note that most water molecules in the human body are not free flowing, they're bonded to something else (i.e. "unavailable"). Without knowing if this power can affect water molecules that are bonded to another substance, there is no way to do a reality check on it

Comment: Sorry, read rules, hopeful this is enough info: For the sake of the question and my understanding/learning, let's say the hydrokinesis can control water at any speed, amount, and volume needed, ignore energy source required. Not 100% sure what you mean by heating up the liquid but let's say using telekinesis doesn't heat things up any more than Magneto does. The hydrokinesis affects water that a magnetic field would like Nyra's example below. "Realistically practical" means being used in the car example I gave. The water can be controlled at a molecular level if needed, but has to stay liquid.

Comment: Welcome to Worldbuilding, if nobody did that already! While every Stack Exchange site has its own distinct differences, Worldbuilding is “more different” in some ways. In particular, you ought not Accept an answer before waiting at least 24 hours. A full explaination can be found on [this meta post](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5023).

Comment: @JDlugosz Alright, thanks for the welcome and information. I've unaccepted/unchecked the answer for now

Answer (score 8, accepted):

## Perhaps.

Affecting the water in a human body would be enough to make it accelerate and, actually, we *already* know it would work - frozen meat and a couple of live frogs have been subjected to this technique.

**But** what exactly happens to the organism subject to hydrokinesis? The live frogs survived "with no ill effects", but frogs are cold-blooded organisms and can (not always, not all) survive freezing. So, an almost complete *temporary* loss of significant relative motion in fluids within a frog might have no effects on it, and yet would be enough to kill a human being.

Even if it did not kill, hydrokinetically accelerating a brain seems more than enough for that brain to *lose concentration* (if not consciousness altogether), which means that immediately after takeoff, our hydrokinetic guy would crash to the ground (or, if the effect is self-sustaining, proceed slowly but surely to leave Earth's orbit or die and fall down, whichever comes first).

Possibly, the control over hydrokinetics could be subtle enough to allow normal motions in fluids while superimposing an overall acceleration effect; or precise and strong enough to accelerate the fluids just below the skin, and maybe on different body areas in turn, so that the body keeps accelerating but no single part is left too long without blood circulation or with excessive pressure (at that point, the guy could also wear an inflatable lifejacket inflated with water, and equip an instant Jet-Pack).

Another interesting possibility is **"reverse" hydrokinetics**. Water exists, in the form of water vapour, about one to forty grams per cubic meter of air, all around us. Our hydrokinetic ESPer would weigh, say, about 80,000 grams; if they can "grab" all the water in the air in a radius of, say, twenty meters, and accelerate it downward, Newton's Third Law would ensure that they would be subject to an upward thrust sufficient to fly. They would become a sort of "human turbine". By forcing the air to go around them at a short distance, they'd produce a safe "bubble" of reasonably still air. This would still require a lot of control, but not so fine as the "affect water within your cells" method.

Comment: Thank you for this detailed answer, it addresses a lot of specific things I was wondering about but didn't know how to explain. I agree with what you and Nyra suggested about easier solutions, but it's still convenient to know what would be required for just using the body alone. I figured something complicated would be required to maintain important bodily fluid flows.

Comment: @LSerni Cool idea about the "reverse" hydrokinetics. 

Also the people that levitated the frog also levitated a mouse, suggesting that it is probably safe for mammals.  he person.

Answer (score 6):

Could hydrokinesis be used to fly, Yes, it could.

I was going to try an calculate the numbers, then remembered that people have levitated a frog [using magnets](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KlJsVqc0ywM) (and [few](https://thekidshouldseethis.com/post/12794114359) other [pages](https://www.ru.nl/hfml/research/levitation/diamagnetic-levitation/)), they levitated it using a magnet to repel the water. Therefore is is possible to accelerate at the very least $1g$ (at least horizontally) at this acceleration you go from $0$ to $100km/h$ in 2.8 seconds, which is about that of a [fast car](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_fastest_production_cars_by_acceleration). Vertical acceleration would be less, but even at $0.25g$ you can climb $100m$ in 9 seconds and $200m$ in 12.5 seconds. They could get to the top of [Mount Everest](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mount_Everest) in less then $1\frac{1}{2}$ minutes.

[image]

So yes you can move living organisms by moving the water in them. AS to how they would use there powers they would just have push each water molecule in the direction of travel and not affect is other motion, so that blood can still flow.

hopefully that helps

*An alternate method that could get used; is if they have strong container, filled water (like a metal water bottle) and then lifted the water in the container. Depending on how much force they can cause the water to push, they could have bracelets/anklets that contain a small amount of water, which they lift, which in turn lifts themselves. Somewhat like [magneto](https://www.reddit.com/r/AskScienceFiction/comments/2jphon/xmen_how_does_magneto_manage_to_fly/) from the xmen, except instead of metal they have water.*

Comment: This does help, I think you get what I intended. I'll see what other people have to say as well. The other method is also worth considering, even if it wasn't what I asked.

Comment: @jrw352 glad to hear; the other idea was something that went through my head when thinking about hydrokinetic levitation, so i would tack it on the end. And whist they may not be needed for levitation (at least of anything with water in)  it they could be used to interact with objects the don't contain water.

Comment: That's a good point.

Answer (score 5):

## Yes; easily.

This answer could definitely be improved with a more detailed look at the statistical distribution of speeds of water molecules at body temperature and the mean free path of the water molecules in a cell to calculate the average speed gain under an e.g. 1g vertical acceleration; however I think the order of magnitude of the velocities here is enough to answer relatively conclusively without that.

The mean speed of a water molecule at standard temperature and pressure is about 590 metres per second. An acceleration of the order of magnitude of 1g is going to make a miniscule effect on the speed of each water molecule in the human body before it collides with something other than a water molecule and transfers some of this momentum to the 40% of the body not directly accelerated. As such, accelerating a human body by only accelerating its water content should not be expected to cause any abnormal effects or stresses on the internal body, so long as the change in velocity between collisions remains small compared to the normal molecular velocities of the water molecules in the body.

Given the tiny intermolecular distances and the significant velocity of water molecules at body temperature, hydrokineses could even potentially allow much stronger accelerations than the human body can usually handle, since the body will be accelerating relatively uniformly throughout, rather than from the feet or back with all the impacts on blood pressure that follow from that. However, I'd definitely want someone to have done a much fuller treatment of the hydrodynamics before trusting my own life to it.

Comment: Very insightful answer. I hadn't considered it from this perspective. I understand your doubts about it, but I still consider this a helpful answer!

Comment: Nice answer, I hadn't thought of approaching the calculations through the velocity.